# 'Device or resource busy' with cdrskin

Tags: live-cd, cd, devices, burning

I am trying to burn an iso (`myiso.iso`) on an empty CD R with `cdrskin`, I get the following error however:

```
# cdrskin  myiso.iso
cdrskin 1.4.6 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
cdrskin: SORRY : Cannot open busy device '/dev/sr0'
cdrskin: ( Most recent system error: 16  'Device or resource busy' )
cdrskin: SORRY : Cannot open busy device '/dev/sr0'
cdrskin: ( Most recent system error: 16  'Device or resource busy' )
cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done
cdrskin: NOTE : No usable drive detected.
cdrskin: FATAL : No drive found. Cannot prepare track.
cdrskin: FATAL : failed to attach fifo.
```

How can I identify the programs that uses the device?

`lsof /dev/sr0` and `fuser /dev/sr0` do not produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the program as root? Most of the time when accessing cds or disk drives, ubuntu has permission issues when trying to access as the current user.

Comment: I'm am running the. command as root

Comment: What ubuntu are you using? Have you tried with brasero or startup disk creator?

Comment: I had a partition mounted on /media

Comment: That had the image on it? Move the file to a partition outside of /media ive had issues in the past with permissions and access issues when i had something mounted there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mount | fgrep sr0
```

The cdrskin message indicates that some process has the device file
open with flag `O_EXCL` in its Linux specific meaning for device files.
This is not an access permission problem but rather a locking protocol
among mount and burn programs.

Now `lsof` and `fuser` seem not detect `mount` on `/dev/sr4`.
I just tested on Debian 8, kernel 3.16. No output.

If i open mounted `/dev/sr4` by some user process, it gets detected by 
`fuser` but not by `lsof`.

As soon as i unmount the drive, `lsof` finds the user process.

---

Last resort:

`cdrskin` has an option `--drive_not_o_excl` which disables the locking
mechanism. I just tested that with this option, a mounted `/dev/sr4`
can be accessed by `cdrskin`.

Of course, one cannot predict what effect this might have on the invisible
user process of the file, or whether that user will interfere with the
CD burn run.